# jQuery push array inserts comma

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have few select boxes with same class. But when I use jQuery array push method to get all selected values in that class as an array it simply adds a comma (,) before each values.
It works fins with static values. Issue is when I add values to select box from a PHP array.
Here is how my select boxes code looks like

```
<select name="add_purch_item1" class="add_purch_item">
    <option value="">----select----</option>
    <?php if(!empty($pro_list1)) { foreach($pro_list1 as $products) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $products->sku; ?>"><?php echo $products->product_name; ?></option>
    <?php } } ?>
</select>

<select name="add_purch_item2" class="add_purch_item">
    <option value="">----select----</option>
    <?php if(!empty($pro_list2)) { foreach($pro_list2 as $products) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $products->sku; ?>"><?php echo $products->product_name; ?></option>
    <?php } } ?>
</select>
```

And I have added a click function to a button. When clicks it will get all selected values as an array. here is my jQuery code,

```
var selected = [];

    $('.add_purch_item').each(function () {
        selected.push($(this).val());
    });

    alert(selected);
```

And when I try select box with static values it gives correct output. **[See here an example](http://jsfiddle.net/joelsays/88nps80a/)**

I am getting this wrong output in dynamic values. That unwanted comma is my issue. How to avoid that? I have tried string replace too.
[image: Wrong Output]

Comment: Can you please post your full code. A fiddle that works isn't really helpful for diagnosing the issue.

Comment: The only reason I can see is there could be an empty value

Comment: What you mean by full code? Which code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is happening because blank values are also inserted. You need to check that selected value is not blank before inserting.

```
$('.add_purch_item').each(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val) {
        selected.push(val);
    }
});
```

[**See updated fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/88nps80a/1/)

Answer (score 1):

It happens where you have blank select elements(where value is not selected). So when you create the array ignore select elements where there is no value selected.

```js
$(document).on("click", '#submit', function() {
  var selected = [];

  var selected = $('.add_purch_item').map(function() {
    return $(this).val() || undefined;
  }).get();

  alert(selected);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="name1" class="add_purch_item">
  <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>
  <option value="1">value1</option>
  <option value="2">value2</option>
</select>

<select name="name2" class="add_purch_item">
  <option value="" selected="selected">-----</option>
  <option value="1">value1</option>
  <option value="2">value2</option>
</select>
<button id="submit">Check</button>
```